# How can I change UserManager logic so that user must exist in database before they register

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, token, dbcontext, two-factor-authentication, usermanager

I am customizing the MVC5 registration process so that when users are registering they must enter two custom fields 'MyNewField1' and 'MyNewField2' which will be then checked against the user context to ensure if they exist in which case the registration can succeed by updating that current user.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> CustomRegister(CustomRegisterViewModel model)
  {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(a => a.MyNewField1== model.MyNewField1& a.MyNewField2== a.MyNewField2).SingleOrDefault();

            if(user != null)
            {
                var emailCheck = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

                if (emailCheck == null)
                {
                    //We have found a user and email address has not been already assigned to another
                    //assign the email entered for this user in place of the username and email place
                    //holders and update the user before saving to the database
                    user.UserName = model.Email;
                    user.Email = model.Email;
                    var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
                    user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(model.Password);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Budget Energy Email Verification", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                    ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;

                    ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed before you can log in.";
                    return View("Info");

                }
                else
                {
                    //This email address is already assigned to a user
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No user exists with these details so redisplay form
                return View(model);
            }
    }        
}
```

This method is passing off successfully and I am being informed that an email has been sent however when I click on this email link I am taken to an error page with the error being Invalid Token. Because I have changed the logic here do I have to create a token in a different manner?

Comment: anyone got any thoughts on this? Bounty of 50 available if you can help me out please

Comment: The problem isnt your logic it's the token.

Comment: You know what I am doing wrong with the token? Any ideas how I can generate a valid token? I had hoped my logic was sound but cannot seem to find a way to generate a valid token for the email confirmation, I think I might need to create a security stamp using a similar way as I have called the relevant class for the password hashing

Comment: There are several reasons why you can get an invalid token. Show a token that it generates and the url that is used.

Comment: How can I generate a token that will be valid based on my logic approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> BillpayRegister(BillpayRegisterViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {                
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ApplicationUser customer = context.Users.Where(a => a.MyNewField1 == model.MyNewField1 & a.MyNewField2 == model.MyNewField2).SingleOrDefault();

            if(customer != null)
            {
                var emailCheck = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);

                if (emailCheck == null)
                {
                    //We have found a user and email address has not been already assigned to another
                    //assign the email entered for this user in place of the username and email place
                    //holders and update the user before saving to the database
                    var user = UserManager.FindById(customer.Id);
                    user.UserName = model.Email;
                    UserManager.SetEmail(user.Id, model.Email);                        
                    string hashedNewPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.Password);
                    user.PasswordHash = hashedNewPassword;
                    var result = UserManager.Update(user); 
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Email Verification", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                        ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;

                        ViewBag.Message = "Check your email and confirm your account, you must be confirmed before you can log in.";
                        return View("Info");
                    }                                                
                }
                else
                {
                    //This email address is already assigned to a user
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //No user exists with these details so redisplay form
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```